# How to specify a jdbc.url in the persistence.xml relative to the application folder?

Tags: java, deployment, jdbc, jpa-2.0, persistence.xml

Once I deploy my application with JPA the user chooses to install it somewhere. Then however the property set as:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:db;create=true"/>
```

gets interpreted into the following exception:
couldn't create database in \db.
Throughout development it used to be the relative path to the project folder, and not the root as it's now.
What should I do to make the path remain relative to the folder in which the application is installed?
Or at the very worse, the userdir.

Answer (score 2):

You should write the install location somewhere and set the `derby.system.home` system property to this location before creating the connection. Quoting the [Using Java DB in Desktop Applications](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javadb/) article:

> #### Connecting to the Java DB Database
>
> ...
>
> All connection URLs have the following
>   form:
>
> ```
> jdbc:derby:<dbName>[propertyList]
> ```
>
> The `dbName` portion of the URL
>   identifies a specific database. A
>   database can be in one of many
>   locations: in the current working
>   directory, on the classpath, in a JAR
>   file, in a specific Java DB database
>   home directory, or in an absolute
>   location on your file system. **The
>   easiest way to manage your database
>   location in an embedded environment is
>   to set the `derby.system.home` system
>   property. This property tells Java DB
>   the default home location of all
>   databases**. By setting this property,
>   the Address Book demo ensures that
>   Java DB always finds the correct
>   application database. The application
>   database is named `DefaultAddressBook`,
>   and it will exist within the directory
>   indicated by the `derby.system.home`
>   property. The connection URL for this
>   database would look like this:
>
> ```
> jdbc:derby:DefaultAddressBook
> ```
>
> ...
>
> To connect to the `DefaultAddressBook`
>   database, the demo must first set the
>   `derby.system.home` system property.
>   The demo uses the `.addressbook`
>   subdirectory of the user's home
>   directory. Use the System class to
>   find out the user's home directory.
>   Then use the class again to set the
>   `derby.system.home` property:
>
> ```
> private void setDBSystemDir() {
>     // Decide on the db system directory: <userhome>/.addressbook/
>     String userHomeDir = System.getProperty("user.home", ".");
>     String systemDir = userHomeDir + "/.addressbook";
>
>     // Set the db system directory.
>     System.setProperty("derby.system.home", systemDir);
> }
> ```

Comment: I cannot know the installation directory (it's handled by a 3rd party installer). The wierd thing is that the current directory, i.e. new File(".") is root!

Comment: @simpatico: Then maybe use the user's home. PS: A good installer should store the installation path somewhere (for uninstall).

Comment: Even that is taken as /!
I think this is a problem by itself. Why doesn't user.dir reflect the actual working directory?

Comment: @simpatico - *"Why doesn't user.dir reflect the actual working directory? "*  Perhaps it does reflect th actual working directory!  It depends (in part) on the nature of the application, and the way that it is launched.  For instance, a wrapper might change directory to "/" before launching the application.

Comment: The lack of effective tools for managing the notion of “current directory” is one of the big lacks in Java, alas.